# Making Async my existing API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

```
public **HttpResponseMessage** GetContacts()  
{  
   var result = db.Contacts().ToList();  
   return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result);  
}
```

to make this call ASYNC, is it enough to add "async Task<>" to the return call:

```
public **async Task<HttpResponseMessage>** GetContacts()  
{  
   var result = db.Contacts().ToList();  
   return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result);  
}
```

or since it's also calling the database, I have to make all/some inside calls async too:

```
public **async Task<HttpResponseMessage>** GetContacts()  
{  
   var result = **await** db.Contacts().ToList();  
   return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result);  
}
```

Comment: Please state what the question/problem/purpose is.What have you tried up to now?

Comment: It looks like you don't actually understand how `async`-`await` works. Have you tried looking at some introduction to it?

Comment: @both ...before I posted this I tried at least 4-5 options that I found on the internet. Should I post everything i've tried so far related to the many hours of research before coming to Stack ...on the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only use `async` when you need it. Generally, it works best by changing the lowest level first; i.e., find blocking methods in your code and make them asynchronous first.

So, with starting code like

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetContacts()
{
  var result = db.Contacts().ToList();
  return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result);
}
```

The first thing to change is `ToList`, which becomes `ToListAsync` and is awaited:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetContacts()
{
  var result = await db.Contacts().ToListAsync();
  return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result);
}
```

Then, because you're using `await`, your method must be marked as `async`:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetContactsAsync()
{
  var result = await db.Contacts().ToListAsync();
  return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result);
}
```

You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Comment: Love your way to explain things. Quick question: what's the best way to "find out" what method is more blocking then others?

Comment: It's a method that causes a thread to enter a wait state for a non-trivial amount of time. I'm not sure of an easy way to "detect" these (without triggering false positives such as thread synchronization). As a general rule, most naturally-asynchronous methods use I/O, so DB communication, web requests, disk I/O, etc. By the time you make all your I/O asynchronous, you will have removed most or all of your blocking.

Comment: Stephen on a scenario with API calls that currently take normally 0.3 seconds, would you still consider "async" them if they have some Database interaction? BTW, love your async intro !!

Comment: @Johnny: I would; 0.3s is quite a long time for a computer. Another consideration is that `async` helps your code deal with unpredictable delays, so if the DB suddenly gets busy, that problem won't cascade to your ASP.NET service. However, if your requests always hit the DB and if your backend is just a single SQL Server instance, then there's usually no point in converting to `async` because SQL Server can't scale as far as ASP.NET anyway.

Comment: Good point. But then why is MS focusing on making ADO.Net Asyncable? I'm using EF6 and from what I get, they don't have a way to Async Stored Procedures (Database first).

Comment: @Johnny: If you have a SQL Server *cluster*, or you're using Azure SQL, then asynchronous database access should always be used.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, in order to make it async you should make sure that you have an asynchornous call inside your method, otherwise there will be no difference.

If you do it like in the second example you gave, you will have an asynchronous method. Note however that this does not impact the client at all. The only thing it will do is free up a thread on the server while the database call is executing.

Comment: Did you mean example #2 on my initial question or #2 on the response? Also is there a difference between #2 and #3 in terms of performance or execution?

Comment: Like I said, just adding the keyword does not make it asynchronous. You actually have to do something asynchronous to make it free a thread. Also, from the point of view of a single call, you won't gain anything, since the request still needs be executed. You may perceive increased performance with multiple calls, because your threads will not be waiting on the database call and thus can handle more requests at once.